# MySQL update query produces null pointer exception

Tags: java, mysql, sql, nullpointerexception

I have a MySQL update query that runs when a user types in the `/pardon` command, but my MySQL `PreparedStatement` try/catch is creating a `NullPointerException`.

**Here is the *updated* stack trace:**

```
[19:28:19] [Server thread/WARN]: java.lang.NullPointerException
[19:28:19] [Server thread/WARN]:    at net.coded.playerdata.cmds.Pardon.onCommand(Pardon.java:50)
[19:28:19] [Server thread/WARN]:    at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:44)
[19:28:19] [Server thread/WARN]:    at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:180)
[19:28:19] [Server thread/WARN]:    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_7_R3.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:703)
[19:28:19] [Server thread/WARN]:    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_7_R3.CraftServer.dispatchServerCommand(CraftServer.java:690)
[19:28:19] [Server thread/WARN]:    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.DedicatedServer.aB(DedicatedServer.java:296)
[19:28:19] [Server thread/WARN]:    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.DedicatedServer.v(DedicatedServer.java:261)
[19:28:19] [Server thread/WARN]:    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.MinecraftServer.u(MinecraftServer.java:558)
[19:28:19] [Server thread/WARN]:    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:469)
[19:28:19] [Server thread/WARN]:    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.ThreadServerApplication.run(SourceFile:628)
```

**Here is the class:**

```
public class Pardon implements CommandExecutor {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args) {

        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("pardon")) {

            if (!sender.hasPermission("bukkit.command.unban.player") || (!sender.isOp())) {
                MessageManager.getInstance().severe(sender, ChatColor.RED + "You do not have permission to do that.");
                return true;
            }

            if (args.length == 0) {
                MessageManager.getInstance().severe(sender, "You must specify a player name!");
                return true;
            }

            if (args.length >= 1) {
                //Unban the player when they are offline
                Bukkit.getOfflinePlayer(args[0]).setBanned(false);
                Player toUnban = Bukkit.getPlayer(args[0]);

                // Update database
                try {
                    Class.forName(PlayerData.driver).newInstance();
                    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(PlayerData.url + PlayerData.dbName, PlayerData.userName, PlayerData.password);

                    String query = "UPDATE playerdata SET banned = ?, ban_reason = ? WHERE uuid = ?";

                    // create the MySQL insert preparedstatement
                    PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
                    preparedStmt.setInt(1, 0);
                    preparedStmt.setString(2, null);
                    preparedStmt.setString(3, toUnban.getUniqueId().toString());

                    // execute the preparedstatement
                    preparedStmt.executeUpdate();
                    conn.close();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                Command.broadcastCommandMessage(sender, ChatColor.GREEN + "Player " + ChatColor.WHITE + args[0] + ChatColor.GREEN + " has been unbanned.");
                return true;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Here is the if statement that is causing the issue:**

```
if (args.length >= 1) {
                //Unban the player when they are offline
                Bukkit.getOfflinePlayer(args[0]).setBanned(false);
                Player toUnban = Bukkit.getPlayer(args[0]);

                // Update database
                try {
                    Class.forName(PlayerData.driver).newInstance();
                    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(PlayerData.url + PlayerData.dbName, PlayerData.userName, PlayerData.password);

                    String query = "UPDATE playerdata SET banned = ?, ban_reason = ? WHERE uuid = ?";

                    // create the MySQL insert preparedstatement
                    PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
                    preparedStmt.setInt(1, 0);
                    preparedStmt.setString(2, null);
                    preparedStmt.setString(3, toUnban.getUniqueId().toString());

                    // execute the preparedstatement
                    preparedStmt.executeUpdate();
                    conn.close();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                Command.broadcastCommandMessage(sender, ChatColor.GREEN + "Player " + ChatColor.WHITE + args[0] + ChatColor.GREEN + " has been unbanned.");
                return true;
            }
```

I have tried creating a separate method for the statement/query, adding a `finally` clause to close the connections, instead of closing them in the `try`. I have also attempted to declare the `Connection`, `PreparedStatement`, and query string before the `try`. I'm fairly sure this is mostly valid code, as I've used the MySQL and Java documentation to write this. I've got to be missing something. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Any stacktrace? (Please update question! Don't post the stack trace as comment.)

Comment: Saw it. Which line is `Pardon.java:54`?

Comment: Stacktrace is not always necessary, just point out which statement produces the error.

Comment: @ADTC Line 54 appears to be: `conn.close();`

Comment: @swiftsly What do you mean by *"appears to be"*? Please look at the source code and check what statement is at line 54. You should be able to see line numbers at the left side (if this feature is enabled) or the current line number on the status bar of your editor. **Also,** I highly doubt it is `conn.close()` since `conn.prepareStatement` was called a few lines before that, so `conn` can't be `null`.

Comment: @ADTC Re-ran of the command a few times just to make sure, and it is   `preparedStmt.setString(3, toUnban.getUniqueId().toString());` Updated the post with the new stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it is `preparedStmt.setString(3, toUnban.getUniqueId().toString());`

According to your comments, it appears that either `toUnban` or `toUnban.getUniqueId()` is a `null` value. Add debug statements likewise and run again to check:

```
preparedStmt.setString(2, null);
System.out.println("toUnban null? " + (toUnban==null));
System.out.println("toUnban.getUniqueId() null? " + (toUnban.getUniqueId()==null));
preparedStmt.setString(3, toUnban.getUniqueId().toString());
```

If either of the debug outputs states `true`, investigate why the corresponding variable is `null`.